# Project Application Services is offline or does not exist.

Tags: 2013, sharepoint-server, project-server

I have a sharepoint servr 2013 and in it ms project server 2013 installed and worked well both of them until today that all users can not access to projects site because of permission(!) and when i want to check status of project server,

when i want to open ms project server application service in central admin `Manage service application`, this error happened :

[image]

And this is `uls` log :

[image]

And project server application service is started :

[image]

And project service application stuck in upgrading :

[image]

Answer (score 0):

For the project server application service, you could wait for a period of the time until the upgrading finished.

If the issue still exists, you could delete the project service application and re-create the project server service application.

Comment: thanks, two days that i'm waiting for finishing upgrading and stuck in this state,
if delete the project service application my sites will be deleted or exist ?

Comment: No, if you delete the project server service application, the site will not be deleted.